# Difference between const int &x = 4 and const int x = 4

Tags: c++, reference, constants

The sole purpose of references is aliasing. Assigning a reference (referring to a constant int) to a integer seems absurd since it is not an alias (and it doesn't give an error!). I suppose it is similar to defining a constant int itself. Is there any difference?

Comment: *difference* in which sense? From the language point of view, there *is* a difference. Practically, there is no difference for this particular case.

Comment: Context matters. Is this a formal argument or not?

Answer (score 2):

Within a function body or file scope, the only difference is `decltype(x)`.  In one case, it is `int const` and the other `int const&`.

The `const int & x=7;` creates a temporary anonymous `int` with value `7`.  It then binds a reference `x` to it.  The lifetime of the temporary is the extended to that of the reference.  This is basically indistinguishable from `x` being the name of a `const int` with value `7`.

An exception to it being nigh identical is when the binding occurs within an object's constructor as part of member initialization.  In that case, the lifetime is not extended.

I suspect you can induce this with:

```
struct Foo{
  int const& x=7;
  Foo(){};
};
```

Either the above syntax is illegal or it dangles (I do not recall if there is a corner case in the standard for references), while:

```
struct Foo{
  int const x=7;
  Foo(){};
};
```

is both legal and does not dangle.  So there is a difference.

There would also be a difference as a parameter to a function, wbhere `=7` simply provides a default.